# Z80 Status Flag registers

Tags: cpu-registers, z80

This will very likely look like a very simple question to some, but when looking at the following register schema:

[image]

and considering that the 'general' flag register is an 8-bit representation of the flag bits, I'm wondering:

Does the 'alternate' F' register always point to the exact same flag bits, or can it contain a different byte in any way (I know alternate registers can not be directly accessed but only be swapped in).

In other words, are the byte contents of 'general' register F content always equal to 'alternate' register F' (representing the same unique flag bits - assuming the 'swap the alternate register' instruction does not alter the flag bits) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are completely different. Alt-F is simply the flag register for the Alt-set.

Comment: Thanks! So if I understand it correctly, does this also mean that the flag bits (in the diagram next to the PC) at each moment in time represent either the contents of the F OR F' register (just after a potential swap has taken place)? In other words, if the alternative register set gets swapped in, will all flag bits (next to the PC) potentially be altered?

Comment: Precisely. You got it.

Comment: If it helps at all, the alternative registers were meant for fast interrupt response: use `exx` and/or `ex af, af'` to preserve a bunch of state on entry, do whatever you want in the other registers, switch back before exit. So the registers are necessarily completely separate. The 8080 doesn't have them at all, if memory serves, so they'd be immediately useful for running that code.